# How to get a value from database for validation purpose in PHP?

Tags: php, database, validation

I have a user level field in my database that contains either 1 or 2. what I want to do is to get the row that has the username that I inputted that contains level 2. Here is my code:

```
<?php

    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("nnx",$con);

    $tbl=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($tbl))
    {

       if (($row['level']=='2')&&($row['username']==$_POST['user']))
       {
            echo $row['username']."".$row['garlique']."".$row['rightcee'];
        echo $row['oleia']."<br />";
       }
       else
       {
        echo $row['username']."".$row['garlique']."".$row['rightcee'];
        echo .$row['oleia']."<br />";
       }
        }
?>
```

When I tried to test it, an error `"unexpected $end"` showed. What I think is wrong in my code is the validation if.. `($row['level']=='2')`.. I don't have any idea how to fix this kind of problem. I am a beginner in php, so if you could help me out, I would appreciate it very much. :)

Comment: You don't seem to be closing your while loop

Comment: If you still get problem after adding while loop closing bracket... Then share your database table structure and it will get solved easily. Because After this you can have error in giving field names wrongly.. otherwise your code seems fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close your `while` loop with `}`. Syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to make a suggestion. If your goal is, as stated, to retrieve the row of the given username that is level 2, your query could do all the work:

```
// Put the username in a variable, making sure it's safe for SQL by escaping it
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);

// Grab the row from the table, expecting only a single result
$tbl = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `level` = '2' LIMIT 1");

// Set your row variables
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($tbl);
$row  = $rows[0];

if (!$row)
{
    // Either not a valid username or the username isn't level 2
}
else
{
    // Valid row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget the last }

```
<?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("nnx",$con);

    $tbl=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($tbl))
    {

        if (($row['level']=='2')&&($row['username']==$_POST['user']))
        {
            echo $row['username']."".$row['garlique']."".$row['rightcee']."".$row['oleia'];
            echo "<br />";
        } else {
            echo $row['username']."".$row['garlique']."".$row['rightcee']."".$row['oleia'];
            echo "<br />";
        }
    } // PAY ATTENTION TO THIS!!
?>
```